# Select a word by cursor and get its position in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small Qt/C++ application with a `QTextEdit` which uploads some text. I want to be able to select a separate word by cursor and to get its position in the text.

For example, in the following sentence: "It is a sunny day".
If I select the word 'sunny', I will get the `int` 4, as it is placed at the 4th position in the sentence.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is a QTextField? There is no such thing in Qt

Comment: my fault, i just mean some text area which is uploading text

Comment: You need to specify what object : QLabel, QTextEdit, QTextBrowser ?

Comment: in my case it is TextEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to :

1. Get the field's text as `QString` using `QTextEdit::text()` method
2. Use `QTextEdit.textCursor()->selectionEnd()` to know where selection ends.
3. Use `QString::mid` to get the substring from 0 to end of selection
4. Use `QString::count` to know how many spaces it contains. This will give you access to the word's position.

Something like:

```
textEdit.text().mid( 0, textEdit.textCursor()->selectionEnd() ).count( ' ' )+1;
```

Hope it helps. That's minimal, you'll probably want to deal with partial word selection or any others relevant corner case.

Comment: i think it is not exactly what i want.
1. i want to choose some word from the text
2. select it in the QTextEdit, by clicking on it for example
3. get exact position of this word even if there are 2 or more similair words in the text